# Primary submodule implies zerodivisors act nilpotently

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a commutative Noetherian ring $R$. Let $N\subseteq M$ be a primary submodule. That is, $\text{Ass}_R(M/N)=\{\mathfrak{p}\}$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq R$. I want to prove:

> Let $r$ be a zerodivisor of $M/N$. Then $r^kM\subseteq N$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

**My thoughts:** I know that we have a finite filtration
$$
0=F_0\subseteq\cdots\subseteq F_n=M/N
$$
where each $F_{i+1}/F_i\cong R/\mathfrak{p_i}$ for some prime $\mathfrak{p_i}\subseteq R$. Moreover, since $\mathfrak{p}$ is an associated prime of $M/N$, I know that $R/\mathfrak{p}$ appears as some of the $R/\mathfrak{p_i}$ in the filtration. Now if $r$ is a zerodivisor of $M/N$, then $r\in\bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Ass}_R(M/N)}\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}$. I'm not sure where to go next. How can I use the filtration to show that $r^kM\subseteq N$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. $r$ acts nilpotently on $M/N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Gopalakrishnana's commutative algebra, Proposition 4 of Page 72 and  Proposition 6 of Page 74] Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. Then $\sqrt{Ann(M)}=\cap_{p\in Ass(M)}p$, and then the set of zero divisors of $M$ is equal
> to  $\cup_{p\in Ass(M)}p$.

By your assumptions and above propositions for the $R$-module $M/N$ we have $\sqrt{Ann(M/N)}=p=$then the set of zero divisors of $M/N$. Thus, if  $r$ is a zerodivisor of $M/N$, then $r\in \sqrt{Ann(M/N)}$, that is, $r^kM\subseteq N$ for some $k\in N$.